# Powershell : How to delete specific format file (.xlsx only) older than X days

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am currently new at PowerShell, I want to delete `.xlsx` files older than X days using Powershell.
I tried below

```
Get-ChildItem D:\temp | ? { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $timeLimit } | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

But above command deleted my all data (including C drive data)

Please suggest a modification or a new command. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well, it didn't delete anything thanks to the `-WhatIf` flag - but what output are you getting exactly?

Comment: @Mathias your edit should be sent as an answer?  Correction `$.PSIsContainer` to `$_.PSIsContainer`?

Comment: @JosefZ I didn't edit that, it was swallowed by formatting before I indented the code block

Comment: Since you have PowerShell 5.0 tagged, you should rely on the `-File` or `-Directory` switch of `Get-ChildItem` and stop using `$_.PSIsContainer`. It is simpler and more readable, IMO.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen sorry then; _mea maxima culpa_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not appear to be filtering for xlsx files in your code.  An xlsx file is not a folder so I have removed that condition from your filter.
`$timelimit` is not defined in the code shown but will need to be of the dateTime type to enable a comparison

```
Get-ChildItem d:\temp -filter "*.xlsx"| ? { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $timeLimit } | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$timeLimit = 60 # Days
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\temp" -Recurse -Include *.xlsx | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$timeLimit)} | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

If this outputs the expected result, you can remove the `-WhatIf` switch and give it a try.